# MemoryLeak in Windows Phone 7.5 / Silverlight app

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I have a Windows Phone 7.5 / Silverlight App.

Each page has 4-5 images, 4-5 storyboard animations and 2 textblocks. It also has 2-3 soundEffects.
User can navigate from page1 to page 15. As soon as I reach page 10 the memory consumption goes beyond 90MB, which is the limit.

I read this: http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/02/01/memory-profiling-for-application-performance.aspx but I am not able to determine exactly what is wrong in my app.

I want to push this app as beta asap but it is failing on Peak Memory Consumption Test when I run Marketplace Test Kit.

Any other pointers or resources?
Thanks.

**Added Images:**
There  are 18 instances of Grid, which is one per page. Is it ok to have an instace of grid to be in the memory even if I have navigated away from the page?
[image]

[image]

**Updated** - Profiler snapshot when memory is above 90Mb: Also as I noted each of my page is in the memory and not sure from where 46 grid instance come from. I have also added GC.Collect when I move to next page. Not sure if that matters.
[image]

**Updated** -Link to code for a control that allow to go to nextpage: http://pastebin.com/ZnBaWfZU

Comment: having some code to look at will help, can't really tell what's wrong without code.

Comment: Run with a memory profiler to see what objects linger. There is a memory profiler built in to at least som editions of visual studio. Otherwise, CLRProfiler is a free download from microsoft.

Comment: @anders, I added the image from Profiler results. I actually don't know how much on how to interpret those results.

Comment: @Mayank, I will have to upload my entire app in that case I guess, which wouldn't be feasible.

Comment: The 18 instances of grid only totals 8k. There has to be more objects allocated than that?

Comment: Are those profiles from after it's hit the 90Mb limit?

Comment: @Rowland, No the profiles isn't after 90Mb limit but just initial stage when it's less than 50Mb. If I select a block of frames in profiler results in other sections, it doesn't give me any warnings. It's only in this section it says "Excessive allocations..."

Comment: @anders, yes lots of images....

Comment: Can you post some of the code that navigates between the pages please, i.e. on navigated from/to

Comment: Also, do you have any background threads doing any work? if so, please specify what they are doing, frequency, etc, and ideally a code sample.

Comment: @Paul: I added code of my control which does the work of moving to next page. See link above in the edits. I don't run any explicit background threads. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re-work my navigation since each page was left behind in the backstack, it was taking up the memory.

Here are few things I did:

1: In the OnNavigateFrom, I had to stop all the animations and set them to null. Same thing for all SoundEffects. Disposed the SoundEffectInstances.

2: In the OnNavigatedTo, I manually calle NavigateService.RemoveBackEntry() to remove the page from backstack and then call GC.Collect().

Hope this helps. Feel free to comment if there's anything wrong using the above solution.

Comment: I think you shouldnot call RemoveBackEntry(), what is user come back again to that page ?

Comment: @entropy that will be a new page load...I have a mechanism in place on where to go when they click back button